# Issue with System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem / NullReferenceException

Tags: powershell

I am getting the following error when I try to get a Listview of Applications in Powershell

```
Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At D:\scripts\AWSA.ps1:527 char:79
+ ... ?{$_.Index -ne 0})){$Field = $Col.Text;$Item.SubItems.Add($_.$Field)}
+                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException
```

The code that is rendering the result is

```
...
$btnApplications = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$lvMain = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
...
$btnApplications_Click={
        Get-ComputerName
        Initialize-Listview
        $SBPStatus.Text = "Retrieving Applications..."
        Update-ContextMenu (Get-Variable cmsApp*)
        $XML.Options.Applications.Property | %{Add-Column $_}
        Resize-Columns
        $Col0 = $lvMain.Columns[0].Text
        $Info = Get-WmiObject win32_Product -ComputerName $ComputerName -ErrorVariable SysError | Sort Name,Vendor
        Start-Sleep -m 250
        if($SysError){$SBPStatus.Text = "[$ComputerName] $SysError"}
        else{
        $Info | %{
            $Item = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.$Col0)
            ForEach ($Col in ($lvMain.Columns | ?{$_.Index -ne 0})){$Field = $Col.Text;$Item.SubItems.Add($_.$Field)}
            $lvMain.Items.Add($Item)
            }
        $SBPStatus.Text = "Ready"
        }
    }
```

Do I need to add a null variable such as `if($SubItem -ne $null){$Item.SubItems.Add($SubItem)}` ?

Comment: You should consider not using semi-colon and putting the remainder on a new line.`;` It will make your code more readable and help you debug / identify errors more clearly. In any case, it seem to me that it is just a typo. Change `$_.$Field` for `$Field`. You are not in a pipeline at that location so `$_` will be null and so `$_.$Field`.

Comment: Unfortunately changing  `$_.$Field` for `$Field` does clear the error, but only displays what the col header is on each row afterward.

Comment: The `$_` in `$_.$Field`  references the current element of the `$Info` collection. Is that the intent? It sounds like that object has no property with a name stored in the value of `$Field`, which would pass `$null` to the `.Add()` call, which probably causes the error. So, yes, if  _some_ `$null` values are to be expected, you'll either need an `if` statement to avoid `.Add()` calls for them, or you can ignore the exception with `try { ... } catch { .. .}`